# Handling an old, viewed and upvoted, but clearly too broad question and its answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, low-quality-posts, needs-more-focus, old-questions

I was reviewing following answer in the Low Quality Posts Queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46128270/5779732

> First get he basic understanding of protocols used in Voip , these are
>   mainly SIP and RTP. Then you can search for any open source protocol
>   stack. http://www.telecomcore.com/p/singaling.html

While reading the answer, I was not sure how to handle this and decided to read question first. When I did, I found the question in itself qualifies for Close/Delete.

I then flagged the question accordingly with most of the answers as NAA.

[VoIP Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5127383/5779732)

> Can someone please guide me on how to make a program of VoIP
>   application in C++?
>
> I've been searching all over the Internet, but I can't even find a
>   tutorial for me to start with. Any references about programming VOIP
>   tutorial in c++ is much appreciated.

OP wants the guidelines to learn a protocol; this is clearly Too Broad, Opinion Based and Off Topic.

The question is too old, is up-voted multiple times, and has multiple up-voted answers with one accepted as well. There is very little one (individual) can do. I am sure just one flag is not enough for closing/deleting the question with its answers.

Should I just handle the answer presented to me while review and neglect the root cause and go on? But this looks useless. That is why my meta question.

How should I handle this question and all its answers?

Comment: That question is off-topic as it's asking for off-site tutorials.  You are right to flag it.

Comment: This 'I've been searching all over the Internet, but I can't even find a tutorial for me to start with' is an excellent clue that the question is very poor quality, the OP has done no research whatsoever and wants you to do it all for them.  If you do that, there will be a follow-up where the OP copies the tutorial code and says 'doesn't work'. etc..etc until you have done their whole job.  Yes, close it now as too broad or off-site - doesn't really mattter how, just get it closed:(

Comment: Please use your question title to describe the thing you're asking about. Titles that just say "...this $whatever..." may as well be blank; they don't give you any idea what you're going to get when you click the link.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Great question! Err, that is, this one *you've* asked on Meta, not [the one you're asking *about*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127383/voip-programming).

What you should be doing here is **flagging/voting to close the question**. Either "too broad" or "off topic → resource request" will do. Don't agonize too much about which is the best choice.

I know that a lot of the answers are pretty low quality, but it is a lot more important that you address the *source* of the problem, which is the question itself, rather than focusing on the answers. Not only will getting the question closed prevent future answers, but it will also make clean-up a lot easier, since we can delete the entire question all at once.

None of those answers are worth salvaging, but there's no point in flagging them all individually, since the question itself isn't salvageable, either.

Focusing on the question itself also keeps a moderator from declining "not an answer" or "very low quality" flags raised on one of the answers on the grounds that the answer *is an answer* to the question that was asked. That's sometimes a problem with resource-recommendation questions, but it can be easily averted by removing the entire question.

Comment: "rather than focusing on the answers" - but what are you supposed to do with the answer in review? Delete? Looks OK? Skip to make it someone else's problem?

Comment: @Dukeling Depends on what review queue…If it's Low Quality Posts, then voting to delete it (if appropriate) is fine. If it's Triage or First Posts, then you probably just want to flag the question and indicate you're done reviewing. (Which is different than what you'd normally want to do, and that is raise a NAA/VLQ flag on the answer.) For clarity, it isn't *wrong* to flag an answer if it meets the threshold for one or the other of those flags, but it doesn't do nearly as much good as dealing with the question itself. And the fact that recommendations are answers to recommendation questions.

Comment: @Dukeling If all reviewers skip the answers that would be great. That means that they have recognized when the queue doesn't show them something they should be focusing efforts own and tackle the source of the problem instead.

Comment: A low quality question deserves a low quality answer.

Comment: @Dukeling: Downvote (on top of any other action). If it ends up deleted you'll get your reputation back, and in the mean time it signals to the answerer that such answers are not welcome.